# Return a list of functions with a given property or creating a group of functions

Tags: hooks, functions, list, isearch

I am a copy editor and I make an intensive use of custom "predicates" when I perform replacements in `LaTeX` code.

I use, among others, this technique:

```el
;; predicate
(defun omit-comments (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is in a comment string."
  (catch 'skip-commented-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (when (nth 4 (syntax-ppss)) (throw 'skip-commented-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))
(defalias 'skip-comments 'omit-comments)

;; predicate
(defun hold-comments (beg end)
  "Return nil if some text BEG to END is outside a comment string."
  (catch 'skip-uncommented-region
    (let ((pos beg))
      (save-excursion
        (save-match-data
          (goto-char pos)
          (while (< pos end)
            (unless (nth 4 (syntax-ppss)) (throw 'skip-uncommented-region nil))
            (goto-char (setq pos (1+ pos)))))
        t))))
(defalias 'keep-comments 'hold-comments)

(defun with-temp-isearch-filter-predicate ()
  "Temporarily assigns a series of predicates to the variable `isearch-filter-predicate`
    to make only portions of the buffer that match specific criteria visible/invisible
    to search and replace functions."
  (interactive)
  (require 'typ-custom-macros)
  (save-excursion
    (let* ((isearch-filter-predicate isearch-filter-predicate)
           (DEFAULT "skip-comments")
           (PREDICATES_LIST '(
                              "keep-comments"
                              "skip-comments"
                              ))
           (PREDICATES (completing-read-multiple
                        "Specify, separating by commas, which predicates you want to activate: "
                        PREDICATES_LIST
                        nil
                        t
                        nil
                        nil
                        DEFAULT))
           
           ;; Non-nil means to allow minibuffer commands while in the minibuffer:
           (enable-recursive-minibuffers t))
      
      (mapcar (lambda (predicate)
                (add-function :before-while isearch-filter-predicate (intern-soft predicate)))
              PREDICATES)
      
      (read-string
       (format
        "The value assigned to the variable `isearch-filter-predicate' is currently `%S'.\nPress ENTER to restore the default value at the end of the operations"
        isearch-filter-predicate)))))
```

Since I have a lot of predicates, I'd like to replace the `PREDICATES_LIST` value, now inserted explicitly in the function, with a more efficient code.

I thought I can define a list, e.g., `my-predicates` and use `(add-to-list 'my-predicates "predicate-name")` but I'm wondering if there is a better solution.

Is there a way to create a "group of functions" or to add to a function name a property, so you can get a list of all the functions in the group or with a given property?

Comment: "I'd like to replace the PREDICATES_LIST value ... with a more efficient code" - more efficient in what sense? Faster to execute (program efficiency)? Easier to modify (programmer efficiency)? Something else?

Comment: I mean "Easier to modify (programmer efficiency)". I'd like to add a function (predicate) to the list/group after the predicate definition code not in the main function body,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group of *anything* is usually going to be a list, and I can't imagine wanting anything different here.

A list of *functions* to be called is typically a "hook" in Emacs.  A hook is still just a list (plus expected naming schemes), but there are a variety of `run-hook*` functions for invoking the functions.  (For user options there's also a `hook` customize type for use in the `defcustom` form.)

Dealing in strings looks kinda gross.  I've only skimmed the code, but it shouldn't be hard to avoid that.  E.g.:

```
(mapcar #'intern (completing-read-multiple "?" '(foo bar baz)))
```

Comment: I searched a lot but I didn't understand if I have to build a simple list of functions or if there is a specific `elisp` syntax to do that.

Comment: There's no specific elisp syntax for a list of functions, because the existing syntax for lists is sufficient.  You can put anything in a list, functions included.

Comment: If you want multiple function lists each identified by some key then you'd likely use an alist or a plist.  See `C-h i g (elisp)Association Lists` and `(elisp)Property Lists` respectively.